# 課長 、明日の会議の企画書、見ていただけたでしょうか。

Tags: grammar

> 課長 、明日の会議の企画書、見ていただけたでしょうか。

Is 見ていただけた some sort of fixed usage or we can put it on other verbs as well? Also, is the translation something like "I wonder (you) were able to see it"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find a duplicate, so I'm going to do a quick breakdown for you.

- いただく is the humble version of もらう

いただく　→　potential form いただける　→　past いただけた

In general (with exceptions), verb te-form + もらう/いただく tells you two things: 1. the action represented by the verb is done by the listener, as opposed to the speaker; 2. it's humbly considered/described by the speaker as a favor granted by the listener.

- でしょうか

でしょうか is a very polite and softened way to ask questions. It follows a variety of sentence structures.

> 課長 、明日の会議の企画書、見ていただけたでしょうか。

thus means:

> 課長 (maybe like manager), have you seen the proposal for tomorrow's meeting (the proposal that will be presented/discussed in tomorrow's meeting)?